# Why am I getting a segfault when assign a char to a pointer to pointer char after realloc space for it?

Tags: c, pointers, char, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I have an double char point guess and I have already malloc space for it and I have realloc for extra characters when enetered to get the right amount of memory allocated. The issue I'm having is that it segfaults whenever it hit `*guess[i] = input` and I cant figure out why ifI pass it \n from stdin it works and passes through the for loop but whenever there are more than one character from stdin it segfaults

Heres the for loop and malloc prior to it

```
char input;
 guess = (char**) malloc(1*sizeof(char));
  for(int i = 0; input != '\n'; i++)
 {
  input = getc(stdin);
  lengthG += 1;
  *guess =(char *) realloc(*guess, lengthG * sizeof(char));
  *guess[i] = input;
 }
```

And heres the whole function

```
int fund_check_input(char *val, char **guess)
{
 size_t lengthV = 0;
 size_t lengthG = 0;
 for(int i = 0; val[i] != '\0'; i++)
 { 

  if(lengthV < 4)
  {  
   if(val[i] < 48 || val[i] > 57)
    return -1;
   else 
    lengthV += 1; 
  }
  else 
   return -1;
 }
 char input;
 guess = (char**) malloc(1*sizeof(char));
  for(int i = 0; input != '\n'; i++)
 {
  input = getc(stdin);
  lengthG += 1;
  *guess =(char *) realloc(*guess, lengthG * sizeof(char));
  *guess[i] = input;
 }
 printf("%s\n", "hey");
 
 
if(lengthG != lengthV)
  return 0;
else
{
 for(int i = 0; *guess[i] != '\0'; i++)
 {
  if(val[i] != *guess[i])
  return 0;
 }
}
 return 1;
}
```

I think that I am allocating enough memory because when I increase the amount being realloc'd it still segfaults, so I am not entirely sure what is happening.

Comment: Unrelated: The term "double pointer" is ambiguous. Someone could think you mean `double *`. Better use the term "pointer to pointer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here

```
guess = (char**) malloc(1*sizeof(char));
                                 ^^^^^
```

you only assign memory for 1 char.

However, it seems you want room for a pointer-to-char.

Did you intend to do:

```
guess = (char**) malloc(1*sizeof(char*));
                                     ^
```

Also notice

1. that the type cast is not needed in C.
2. that `guess = malloc(1*sizeof *guess);` is in general a better form as you avoid typos like the one you did above. (the `1*` can be deleted as well)

That said, consider what the value of `*guess` is after fixing the above error. You need to make sure it's properly initialized before calling `realloc`

Comment: So I changed it to *guess and that makes sense about the casts I just was mimicing what I found online. But for the *guess[i] from my understanding what **guess is derefrencing to the char after the pointer which is *guess and guess is the actual poitner so I would need to derefrence to the pointer header on the memory that allocated to and the [i] selects the byte of the index. I added a check for realloc and its still reaching the segfault so im assuming it is intialized. So I don't understand what could be causeing that segfault still.

Comment: @planetz1 Be careful with `*guess[i]` What does it really mean? Is it `*(guess[i])` or is it `(*guess)[i]` ? These are very different things! Check https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @planetz1 If this answer solved your problem, feel free to accept it.

Comment: Maybe you can add that if OP uses the `* 1`, placing `sizeof()` in front ensures `size_t` arithmetic.

Comment: Also you should note note that OP needs to do the same correction for the call `realloc()`.